# What are the keys of a dictionary that function return?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I work with a function that when you call her it return dictionary,
which command shoud I write that will print the keys of the dictionary?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an iterable object with the keys by calling *your_dict.keys()*

```
>>> my_dict = {'1': 'one', '2': 'two'}
>>> for item in my_dict.keys():
        print(item)
1
2
```

Comment: For the purpose of iterating over the keys, calling `keys()` is not even necessary.

Comment: oh i forgot about that, thank you for pointing it out